# Prevent Scroll.js from Removing Anchor Hashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am using Scroll.js to provide smooth scrolling on a single-page website. It removes the anchor hash from the URL, and I'm trying to prevent this from occurring while maintaining the scroll behavior.

I am not familiar enough with Javascript to edit this code successfully, and perhaps using Scroll.js simply in't a good approach given what I'm after?

Your input is appreciated - thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
 var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
 var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
 var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
 $(this).click(function() {
            $("#nav li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass('active');
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
           return false;
         });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Probably you can't if scroll.js works with anchors. You can try [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead setting it up with [no anchors](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/noAnchor.html) and probably, with [autoScrolling:false](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html). And overwritting the `.fp-section` css to add `height: auto !important1`.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro. I've implemented your plugin and it's really slick!